# Decoding unicode encoded json with node

Tags: node.js, unicode, encoding

I am working with the MailChimp API and it is returning error responses like this:

```
{ 
  statusCode: 400,
  data: '\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003L��\t�0\fF�UJ�N�\u0006NQ�\r%`��\'\n"��Ћ���nb��f\u0012=�&9����i\u001a\'f�\u0015�]�~j\u0019*\u0014$��W��\u0013Reg��_T1\u0013-��\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0003\u0000�;�oc\u0000\u0000\u0000' 
}
```

The content type is JSON - I assume this is unicode encoded. Is there a built in function in Node/JS to decode this? I am only finding homemade implementation - none of which have worked so far.

As per comment `JSON.parse(err.data)` returns junk. And yes this is an object and not a string. Ideas?

Edit. I have tried decoding to utf8, gunzipping, etc but still no go.

Comment: Decode to what? to unicode escapes?

Comment: It's just some binary value encoded in string. You could use `JSON.parse` to get this value, but it's still not really clear what it represents

Comment: Unortunately JSON.parse still renders junk. Its the MaillChimp API error message

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JSON but it's not - the keys are not quoted as required. As mentioned it is a mailchimp error message.

This may help to solve it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mailchimp-api-discuss/S0JrzoEWY_0/94gTLsBjvtUJ - or not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include `gzip: true` to the request configuration, e.g.:

```
const data = await http({
  url: 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  gzip: true,
  form: {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    code,
  },
});
```

This will correctly decode the gibberish that is returned into human readable error messages.